# Create entire DataSet from existing stored procedure

Tags: visual-studio-2010, stored-procedures, dataset, strongly-typed-dataset

I have stored procedures (they accept parameters) that return multiple result sets and I'd like to have this saved in a typed dataSet.

The question is: can I have Visual studio 2010 generate the typed dataset based on stored procedure? I know I can have this for a single table, but I need the whole dataSet (multiple tables, one for each result set)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So let's do an experiment to see if it is possible..

I created the following stored procedure in a SQL 2008 database:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.StackOverflow3668337
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    SELECT 'First bit';

    SELECT 'Second bit';
END
```

Then I created a new project in VS2010, and added a DataSet item to the project.

I created a connection to the database in the Server Explorer, and dragged the 'StackOverflow3668337' item onto the DataSet designer surface. This is the result:

[image: TableAdapter from DataSet Designer]

So that would be just one DataTable. So unfortunately I think the answer is out of the box, "No".

I think the main reason for this is that the [TableAdapter classes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bz9tthwx%28v=VS.90%29.aspx) that are generated are just tied to a single DataTable. You can have multiple TableAdapters for a single DataTable but they all need to return the same data. There is no capacity for a single TableAdapter to interact with additional DataTables.

Answer (score 3):

I know this is old but I cam across this question when I was searching for the same/similar answer. So I figured I would leave what I found here for those that come after me. It isn't auto-magical but this will get you there.

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/322793

**Create Procedure**

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.sp_GetCustOrd
AS
SELECT * FROM Customers;
SELECT * FROM Orders;
```

**Create DataSet**

1. In Visual Studio .NET, on the File menu, point to New, and then click Project.
2. Click Visual Basic Projects under Project Types, and then click Windows Application under Templates.
3. On the View menu, click Server Explorer.
4. In Server Explorer, click Connect to Database, and then connect to your SQL Server Northwind database.
5. Drag the Customers and the Orders tables from Server Explorer to the current project. Notice that a SqlConnection object and two SqlDataAdapter objects are added to the project.
6. In the Properties window, click Generate Dataset, and then add both tables to the DataSet. Notice that an .xsd file is added to the project. The .xsd file is named according to the name that you chose for the DataSet class.

**Add Relations**

1. In Solution Explorer, double-click the .xsd file that you created in the previous section.
2. Right-click the Customers table in the designer, point to Add, and then click New Relation.
3. In the Edit Relation dialog box, select the Orders table as the child element, and then click OK. This creates a new DataRelation named CustomersOrders in the DataSet schema.
4. On the File menu, click Save to save the changes.

**Fill**

```
Dim da As New SqlDataAdapter("sp_GetCustOrd", SqlConnection1)
da.SelectCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
da.TableMappings.Add("Table", "Customers")
da.TableMappings.Add("Table1", "Orders")
Dim ds As New CustOrd()       ' Change this name to match .xsd file name.
da.Fill(ds)
DataGrid1.DataSource = ds
DataGrid1.DataMember = "Customers"
```

I know this example is in VB, and I was looking for the C# answer. But should be easy enough to port over.

Comment: I can confirm this method works. I was able to return two tables in one procedure and populate a strongly typed dataset using this method. I also tested using a parameter to control which table gets returned. This worked but required two calls to da.Fill(ds.Table) and da.Fill(ds.Table1). Not idea, but also works if your only goal is to keep the number of procedures in your database minimized.